# html 5 reset drag and drop position

Tags: jquery, html, drag-and-drop, reset

I have a div that's hidden in a sense, then when you click a link it fades in and another div behind blacks out the rest of the site (light box effect). I have a drag and drop aspect in this div. If you move an object, then close the div (essentially hiding it again and re-revealing the rest of the site) and then RE-OPEN it, the square is already moved instead of reset...

Is there a functionality or method of "resetting" the position of moved elements I could call on the close button? I've searched around and found absolutely nothing that relates to resetting positions of a drag and drop event.

Update, I got it working although is this an effective way of doing things?... :
FIX:

```
function showpanel(){
    $("#lightbox, #lightbox-panel").fadeIn(300);
}
function hidepanel(){
    $("#lightbox, #lightbox-panel").fadeOut(300);
    $("#lightbox-panel").load("main.php #lightbox-panel");
}
```

DnD functions (from w3schools):

```
function allowDrop(ev)
{
ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev)
{
ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text",ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev)
{
ev.preventDefault();
var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
var itemVariable = document.getElementById(data).id.split('-');
}
```

Comment: More info please. Show your code. Also you have tagged this as HTML, DRAG, RESET, and DROP.. Is this using JavaScript, or a JS library like jQuery or MooTools? Or some other objected oriented programming language for that matter.

Comment: It's HTML5/jQuery, I have found a solution... although unsure of it's the most efficient way. Update in question.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the original position on the screen in variables and reset the position manually.

```
//original position is 0,0
var x-position = '0px'; 
var y-position = '0px';
```

and then (I'm assuming you're using JQuery?) in your reset function

```
$('#draggable_object').css('left', x-position).css('top', y-position);
```

Comment: Hmm not a terrible idea, although what if the position can change based on a % of the div's height/width.

Comment: Just calculate the original position with javascript after the page loads. That way you don't have to hard-code anything.